# Cat B15Q pairs with Toyota, but connection unusable

Tags: bluetooth

I have no problems pairing my Cat B15Q (Android 4.4.2) with my 2013 Toyota Auris over Bluetooth. However, it stops there. As soon as I try to use the connection (make a phone call, play music, access the internet), the Toyota complains with a non-descript error message.

I have been able to successfully connect a WinPC with the phone (incl. file transfer).

Does anybody know any tricks? I have tried the obvious ones: deleting the connection, re-pairing. To no avail. The car can use my wife's iPhone 6 over Bluetooth. I have contacted Cat, but they say the problem is with Toyota. When I see the long list of phones compatible with my car, I can only wonder why my phone isn't working and why the problem should be with Toyota?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last week, I had to turn in my (company car) Toyota and I got a Peugeot 2008 in return. Of course I tried to connect the Cat to the car. Pairing was no problem. Making a phone call, however, was not possible. But receiving a phone call was possible! This got me thinking. The Cat is dual SIM and in fact I have two SIM cards. In the settings you can choose which SIM card to use as default for outgoing calls, or whether to postpone that decision when actually making a phone call. I had chosen for the latter option, but after I changed it so that outgoing calls always use one specific SIM card, I could make calls with the car's phone buttons!

Maybe the connection with the Toyota had been successful after all, it just got stuck because I hadn't opted for the default SIM card option.